# Why does loadimage work on laptop but not desktop?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, image-processing, bitmap

This code loads the image on my laptop (WIndows 10 ver 1903) with a good handle. But, it gives a handle of 0 on my desktop (windows 10 ver 1809). Both give an error code of 0.

There may have been some permission changes in my organization, so I'm trying to determine if it is not loading because of permissions.

I can give you bitmap if needed. It is 6MB. But the header is:

42 4D C2 13 
5F 00 00 00 
00 00 1A 00 
00 00 0C 00 
00 00 F3 04
66 06 01 00
18 00 FF FF
FF FF FF FF

```
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr LoadImage(IntPtr hinst, string lpszName, uint uType, int cxDesired, int cyDesired, uint fuLoad);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

                string f = "C:\\Users\\mm\\Desktop\\test.bmp";
                if (File.Exists(f))
                {
                    string newf = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), Path.GetFileName(f));
                    if (File.Exists(newf))
                    {
                        File.Delete(newf);
                    }
                    File.Copy(f, newf);
                    IntPtr s = LoadImage(IntPtr.Zero, newf, 0, 0, 0, 16 | 8192);
                    int er = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString() == "0" ? "Cannot Load File, Result: " + s.ToString() : "Loaded file, Result: " + s.ToString());
```

EDIT: FYI, if I save the image in paint, it loads fine. There is an issue with loadimage only loading a specific bitmap (v4 or v5?), so I'm guessing this may be related.

EDIT2: Alright, I found the answer. I haven't done windows updates on my laptop since december 2019 or before. Once I updated, I cannot load the bitmap using loadimage() on my laptop. It looks like Microsoft changed the way loadimage works in one of their updates. The 0C 00 at the 15th & 16th byte of the header indicates the bmp I'm trying to load is BITMAPCOREHEADER, which is really old. Loadimage cannot load top-down bmps. Also, c:\windows\system32\gdi32full.dll updated to newer version. See these links if interested:

https://www.pentestpartners.com/security-blog/time-travel-debugging-finding-windows-gdi-flaws/

https://www.codeproject.com/script/Content/ViewAssociatedFile.aspx?rzp=%2FKB%2Fgraphics%2FJrsCExBitmap%2FExBmpDemo_src.zip&zep=CDibData%2FCDibData.cpp&obid=5934&obtid=2&ovid=1

Comment: Have you looked at this with SysInternals `Process Monitor`. It will likely point you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing that now. All the LoadImage lines have a success with an Image Base and Image size. It may not be permissions. Still don't know why its working on one machine.

Comment: Change `"C:\\Users\mm\Desktop\test.bmp"` to `"C:\\Users\\mm\\Desktop\\test.bmp"`, and make sure that the `mm` user actually exists on both machines.  A better solution to get the user's actual Desktop folder is to use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)` instead.

Comment: Sorry i put that in the post at the last minute to hide the username. Fixed. That directory does exist.

Comment: In Process Monitor, on the machine that works I get CreateFile, QueryOpen, & QueryBasicInformationFile. On the machine that doesn't work in ProcessMonitor, I get IRP_MJ_CREATE, FASTIO_QUERY_OPEN, & FASTIO_QUERY_INFORMATION

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place for the issue. The issue is with the tool used to author the bitmap image. I'm going to claim that *most* applications write buggy BMP files. MS Paint is very resilient to protocol errors and writes correct BMP files. If in doubt. always load up your BMP files in MS Paint and save them from there prior to having your software attempt to load it.

Comment: Yea, I get a lot of buggy bmps I don't have control over. That is good info though. There is a larger automated process that opens the bmps in imagemagick (to mimic opening them in paint). But all of that is in VB6 (haha). I was thinking there was an OS reason that loadimage does work on these "buggy" bitmaps.

Comment: The [Windows Imaging Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-about-windows-imaging-codec) (which `LoadImage` presumably uses) is extensible. [How the Windows Imaging Component Works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-howwicworks) explains, how custom codecs are installed. That should give you some information to determine, why the image can be loaded on some machines but not others.